# Getting error function to_date(timestamp without time zone, unknown) does not exist

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, jdbc

Recently i have migrated my postgres from 8.2 to 8.4. when I run my application and tried to
login i am getting these error

```
 ERROR [JDBCExceptionReporter] ERROR: function to_date(timestamp without time zone, unknown) does not exist
```

i had checked in my postgres by excecuting these to_date function

```
SELECT  to_date(createddate,'YYYY-MM-DD') FROM  product_trainings;
```

it is giving me error  function to_date does not exist

when i execute the same query in postgres 8.2 i am not getting error

Please help me to resolve these issue.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems like all it needs is a conversion from timestamp to text as function definition is: to_date(text,text).

Perhaps in 8.2 this conversion from timestamp to text was already predefined.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-formatting.html

Answer (score 45):

Three year later. You can cast

```
SELECT
    to_date(cast(createddate as TEXT),'YYYY-MM-DD') 
FROM  
    product_trainings;
```

Answer (score 21):

And even neater:

```
SELECT to_date(createddate::TEXT,'YYYY-MM-DD') 
FROM product_trainings;
```