# How do I group by Date and sum by date duration for two timestamps?

Tags: sql, postgresql

**Input -**

```
ID  utc_tune_start_time utc_tune_end_time
A   04-03-2019 23:00:00 05-03-2019 01:00:00
```

**Desired Output**

```
ID  Date         Duration in Minutes
A   04-03-2019       60
A   05-03-2019       60
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Date functions are notoriously database-specific.

Comment: What data types are those columns?

Answer (score 0):

This may work for you:

```
select 
to_date(cast(utc_start_time as TEXT),'YYYY-MM-DD') date, extract(minute from utc_tune_start_time) duration in minutes from Table
union
to_date(cast(utc_end_time as TEXT),'YYYY-MM-DD') date, extract(minute from utc_tune_end_time) duration in minute from Table
```

EDIT: OP uses PostgreSQL, therefore a modification was needed (conversion from timestamp to text).

Comment: I get the following error - Invalid operation: function to_date(timestamp without time zone) does not exist; A partial run of the code displays the above error. I am using sql workbench/j for my query

Comment: Workbench is IDE, which DBMS are you using? PostgreSQL?

Comment: Yes, PostgresSQL

Comment: Then it looks like your problem was solved here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19947817/getting-error-function-to-datetimestamp-without-time-zone-unknown-does-not-ex.

Comment: Does this to_date(utc_tune_end_time::TEXT,'DD-MM-YYYY') work?

Comment: I did this and it worked -- select 
to_date(cast(utc_start_time as TEXT),'YYYY-MM-DD'), extract(minute from utc_start_time) from table
union
select
to_date(cast(utc_original_end_time as TEXT),'YYYY-MM-DD'), extract(minute from utc_original_end_time) from table

Comment: Cool, I added these changes to my answer.